# Suggestion for IB program Analysis and Approaches SL book?

Tags: secondary-education, textbooks, mathematical-analysis, book

What is the most suitable book for the IB program Analysis and Approaches SL for a student with significant weaknesses?

I had suggested the book from HAESE Mathematics yet he finds it particularly incomprehensible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I looked up that textbook.  The website touts it as part of a "rigorous series of mathematics books for IB students around the world".  If you have a weak, struggling student, why recommend a "rigorous" text?

Here's an alternate, covering most of the same material:  Frank Ayres, Theory and problems of first year college mathematics, [College algebra, plane trigonometry, plane and solid analytic geometry, introduction to calculus] (Schaum's outline series)

[https://www.amazon.com/Theory-problems-first-college-mathematics/dp/B0007DPVM2](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0007DPVM2)

I have a copy of this text and it is very student friendly "precalc" or "college algebra" (but with an intro to calc) book.  (And based on looking at the IB course description for Analysis and Approach, this is the right course translation.)

Also, has all the answers, so very drill friendly.  Deliberately uses simple/less words to help students immediately get the math.  Sure, it's not steeped in IB-ness.  Or in rigor.  But those are features, not bugs, for a weak student.

Comment: To be fair, IB and their associated textbooks call just about everything they do "rigorous" so you can't really go by what they say.

Comment: Wondered about that.  It definitely seems to have a branding aspect.